# JS How does the in operator work on object with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, webkit

Line 64 of this [fullscreen github project](https://github.com/sindresorhus/screenfull.js/blob/gh-pages/src/screenfull.js) checks if an array is in an object, `if (val && val[1] in document)`, like in the example below.

I understand 'in' operator for normal properties but how does this work for arrays? I don't understand how this passes if you are in a webkit browser.

```
const webkit = [
    'webkitRequestFullscreen',
    'webkitExitFullscreen',
    'webkitFullscreenElement',
    'webkitFullscreenEnabled',
    'webkitfullscreenchange',
    'webkitfullscreenerror'
],

if (webkit in document) {
    //Passes
}
```

I'm using JSDOM and need to add these webkit properties to a fake document. I'v tried to replicate this like so:

```
const document = {
    webkitRequestFullscreen = () => null;
    webkitExitFullscreen = () => null;
    webkitFullscreenElement = null;
    webkitFullscreenEnabled = true;
    webkitfullscreenchange = () => null;
    webkitfullscreenerror = () => null;
}
```

but the `in` operator check fails.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'v read that. Still don't see how this works for the example above

Comment: `val[1]` is the value in that array, not the array itself, so your comparison is not the same. If `val[1] = "test"` it would be the same as `"test" in document`

Comment: Just in case this is the source of the confusion: `if (val && val[1] in document)` does *not* check `val in document`.

Comment: @ChrisG That is the source of my confustion. What does it do then?

Comment: It's `if ( (val) && (val[1] in document) )`

Comment: it checks that `val` variable exists (has truthy value), and then if so check if the value at index 1 is in document

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any point to the `val &&` part of the test. It's looping over a literal array that it just created, and none of the elements are empty.

Comment: @ChrisG Of course... My bad.

Comment: `['a'] in {a:0}` returns true while `['a'] in {a:0,b:0}` returns false and `['a','b'] in {a:0,b:0}` returns true (in chrome console). `Array in Object` returns true if all of the array values return true for `value in Object` it seems.

Comment: So the test is effectively like `if (webkit[1] in document)`

Comment: @XerenNarcy I don't get `true` for `['a','b'] in {a:0,b:0}`. The left operand of `in` is converted to a string. When you convert an array to a string, it's equivalent to `array.join(',')`. So `['a','b'] in {a:0,b:0}` is like `'a,b' in {a:0, b:0}`. It's false because there's no property named `'a,b'`.

Comment: Try `['a','b'] in {'a,b':0,b:0}` that returns `true`.

Comment: @Barmar yep. you're right. then i don't know what the point of that code is unless there does exist a key with all of the array values comma separated.

Comment: @XerenNarcy It's not doing what the OP thought. It's just testing a single element of the array, not the whole array.

Comment: @Barmar sure but then what's with this: `if (webkit in document) {
    //Passes
}`

Comment: @XerenNarcy He must have made a mistake, like you did. I don't get true for that, either.